# Angular, wait for one component to render completely before rendering the other

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular component which in turn has two more components in it, I want to make sure that second-component loads/renders only after the first-component is rendered completely, how can I achieve it?

**combined.component.html**

```
<first-component></first-component>
<second-component></second-component>
```

**combined.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'main-component',
    templateUrl: './combined.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./combined.component.css']
})
export class CombimedComponent {

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An easy way to do it would be...

In your first child component add an `EventEmitter` that fires an event after it has been completely loaded like so

**first-component.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewChecked } from 'angular/core';

// ...

@Output() finishedLoading: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

ngAfterViewChecked() {
   // you could also do this after a service call of some sort
   this.finishedLoading.emit(true);
}
```

`ngAfterViewChecked` is the last lifecycle hook run on a component, so at this point the component has been completely loaded!

You can learn more about lifecycle hooks [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Then in your parent container you can set a flag called `hasLoaded`

**combined.component.ts**

```
// ...

hasLoaded: boolean = false;
```

then in your parents component html you can listen for the `finishedLoading` event and then render your second component like so..

**combined.component.ts**

```
<!-- Listens for the finishedLoading event and then sets hasLoaded once its been fired -->
<first-component (finishedLoading)="hasLoaded = $event"></first-component>

<!-- Doesnt render the second component until hasLoaded has been set to true -->
<second-component *ngIf="hasLoaded"></second-component>
```

Comment: This is the best solution.